# Can I get a YouTube user's session data from the YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api

I am a teacher and I have a YouTube channel with videos for my students. Every time one of my students see a video, I would love to know how he interacted with it: where he has paused it , where he has rewinded it, etc. This would help me in knowing the parts of the video that are difficult to understand.

My question is: is it possible to get all this data from a user's session? Specifically, can I get these detailed raw data from YouTube APIs?

From what I have explored so far, it seems that it is not possible, as YouTube APIs only seem to send "aggregated" data (example: total number of views of a video) or "properties" (example: title of the video).

I would really just need a Yes/No answer to my question, just to know if I am not waisting my time in exploring the APIs as a solution to my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no,

But here is a more detailed explanation.

The YouTube Analytics api will give you analytics data on your own YouTube channel, but it wont be user specific you cant track who exactly did something.  You may however be able to get some basic information about each video and what was clicked and how much was viewed. [video reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports#video-reports)   But its not going to be user specific you wont know what Mike did as opposed to what Jane did.

The YouTube Data api will allow you to manage your own YouTube Channel for example upload videos and see subscriptions.   It will also let you search for public videos on YouTube.

If you do want user specific then What you are looking for is session data related to user activity.  Something like this is not publicly available.  Google couldn't share your students activity without the students permission due to GDPR not to mention the fact that tracking anyone under the age of 13 would also be against some GDPR laws if i remember correctly.

Even Google analytics doesn't offer websites a decent way of tracking individual users activity on their websites. You can do it but you have to add additional tracking data to your website, and notify users that you are doing it.

SO your answer is yes kind of

Comment: Thank you, @DalmTo! Concerning user activity and session data: I really don't need the user data (his name, etc.). But it would be interesting to have session data (exampe: during a session, the video was paused 1 time, at 3:45 m ). This information would help me to know what parts of the video are difficult to undestand.
I use Google Analytics to monitor websites, but, again, I guess it wouldn't solve my problem: even if I embed a YouTube Video in my webpage, chances are that Google Analytics will only tell me something about the webpage display, and not video interaction.
Thank you.

Comment: Try checking out YouTube analytics it might get you some of the information you want https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics